# Interactive Language Console

Tags: ruby, console, terminal

I've been doing some browsing on interactive consoles for programming languages such as: http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0 or even better, the tutorials at http://codeschool.com

What would be the best method of trying to implement something like this? I was thinking that you would have to have to use ajax to the server and have it check input etc, but is there a simpler method?

Sorry for such a short question; I honestly don't know how to ask this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tryruby has source code on github at https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby/ . That might give you some ideas.

Here is "A Go tool to safely compile Go programs by only allowing importing whitelisted packages".  You might find that more useful.

https://github.com/zond/gosafe

Comment: I'm sort of asking more of a theory side then browsing through source code on a language I don't know. Thanks though.

Comment: Reading code is a useful way of learning how things are done.

Comment: @tehlulz: you already know the essentials: ajax-post code to the server, evaluate it there and deliver results back to the client. You can decorate this with bells and whistles as you wish :)